# RTS game/mod/usemap about fighting Squidwards in a gay bar

Tags: game-identification

At the start of MadaloreGaming's video review of *Myth: The Fallen Lords*, there's a video reel with early examples of RTS games.

[Between 0:35 and 0:40 mark, there's footage of a half-naked man going around a gay bar and fighting copies of Squidward (from *SpongeBob SquarePants* cartoon)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NDgXXEQpFBQ&t=35s):

[image: video game screenshot: a muscular man, dressed only in briefs, is going right in a room with four Squidwards, while in the background there are 3 pnik signs proclaiming in big white letters: "GAY BAR"]

At the bottom, there's a cropped tooltip that looks eerily similar to tooltips from *World of Warcraft*, suggesting this might be a *Warcraft 3* usemap.

Where is this from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called [Warcraft 3: Canned Bread](https://maps.w3reforged.com/maps/categories/mini-games/canned-bread) and it's indeed a custom map/minigame.

Comment: Oh, wow, that was fast. And I verified that by finding some footage: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Srw-KzS-rsQ